# How to find the coordinate of a point knowing the coordinates of three point

Tags: geometry

If we have a flying drone and in some point we want to find its approximate coordinate in space due to GPS signal malfunctioning. If the drone coordinate is $D$  and we know the location of the three stations ($Q$, $R$ and $Z$) in ground which are defined by latitude and longitude coordinates. We also know the distance between the drone and each of the three stations $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_3$. Can we find a rough estimate for $D$ in terms of latitude and longitude?

Comment: You can set up the trilateration equations. This corresponds to the intersection of 3 spheres, which lead to only 2 possibles solutions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-range_multilateration

Comment: I found the answer here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66/trilateration-using-3-latitude-longitude-points-and-3-distances